# Cognos 10.1 Report Builder If...else if filters

Tags: if-statement, filtering, cognos

I have the current filter set up in Cognos and it works great.

```
if ((?Area?) = 'BEVEL') then
([WorkCenter] in ( 'VG3', 'VG2', 'BERGER', 'BG1', 'BG2', 'HG1', 'HG2', 'HOLLOW'))

else if ((?Area?) = 'BLADEMILL') then ([WorkCenter] in ('BLADE', 'MANUAL')) 

else if((?Area?) = 'FINISH') then  ([WorkCenter] in ('1-FIN', '2-FIN', 'BLAST', 'COAT', 'CTGPRP', 'FINISH', 'HEFS', 'VIBE'))

else ([WorkCenter] is null)
```

However, when I try and add more else if statments I get an error. Any idea if Cognos has a limit to the number of IF statements that can be done? And if they do is there a work around?

Here is everything I want to put in the statement.

```
if ((?Area?) = 'BEVEL') then
([WorkCenter] in ( 'VG3', 'VG2', 'BERGER', 'BG1', 'BG2', 'HG1', 'HG2', 'HOLLOW'))

else if ((?Area?) = 'BLADEMILL') then ([WorkCenter] in ('BLADE', 'MANUAL')) 

else if((?Area?) = 'FINISH') then  ([WorkCenter] in ('1-FIN', '2-FIN', 'BLAST', 'COAT', 'CTGPRP', 'FINISH', 'HEFS', 'VIBE'))

else if ((?Area? = 'GRIND') then ([WorkCenter] in ('1-SURF', '2-SURF', 'SURFAC'))

else if ((?Area? = 'HANDLEMILL') then ([WorkCenter] in ('CUTSAW', 'HANDLE', 'HZMACH'))

else if ((?Area? = 'LASER') then ([WorkCenter] in ('DEBUR', 'LASER', 'LSRPRC'))

else if ((?Area? = 'LINER') then ([WOrkCenter] in ('LNRCEL', 'STAMP'))

else if ((?Area? = 'SCREW') then ([WorkCenter] in ('SR-16'))

else if ((?Area? = 'TIGER') then ([WorkCenter] in ('TIGER'))

else if ((?Area? = 'Gold') then ([WorkCenter] in ('Gold'))

else if ((?Area? = 'ASSEMBLY' then ([WorkCenter] in ('ASSEMB', 'ASYGRP', 'BLEND', 'CLNBOX', 'ENGRAV', 'HKCELL', 'ROBOT', 'SERRAT', 'SHARPN'))

else ([WorkCenter] is null)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Not familliar at all with Cognos, but it might be that each of the additional if-then statements you've added has mis-matched parenthesis.

Comment: Thats exactly what it was...Not sure how I missed that. Thank you so much for pointing that out to me. Works great now.

Comment: Please add the error description....